# Can I use variables to build variable names in SQL statements using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a PHP for loop to insert into a table. I would like to build my variable names dynamically using variables and concatenation inside the SQL statement.

```
    $item1Name = 'blue';
    $item2Name = 'red';
    $item3Name = 'green';
    $item4Name = 'orange';
    $item5Name = 'yellow';

    for ($x=1;$x<5;$x++){   
    $insertItem = "insert into tblInvoiceItems (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item".$x."Name) values";
    $insertItem .= "('','','".$item.$x."Name')";
    runQuery($insertItem,$page);
    }
```

The first line seems to work, but the second one is not.

I am trying to dynamically build these queries:

```
    insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item1Name) values('','','blue')
    insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item2Name) values('','','red')
    insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item3Name) values('','','green')
    insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item4Name) values('','','orange')
    insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item5Name) values('','','yellow')
```

Thanks

Comment: [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: what that mean? Show us current variable value and expected result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: if you build also like that what the use? what value those variables have?

Comment: Thanks Juan, I read both of those pages before I posted. I don't think that is what I am looking for.

Comment: look up http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: eval ("$item".$x."Name") will return the value of actual variable "$item1Name"

Comment: the thing is if he have `$item1Name` available then why not directly to use that?

Comment: it doesn't look like he has that..he's building it from the loop variables

Comment: looks like array can be used here but i am just telling him of how to evaluate variable names if he's manually trying to build it

Comment: When comment use `@` like `@Juan` so user get a notification message. That page wont solve your question the idea is you learn how make a better question so you get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to use array as values storage. Keen in mind that keys ia array begin from `0` not `1`.

is that what you wanted **[DEMO LINK](https://eval.in/598772)** ?

**php code:**

```
<?php

$values = [
    'blue',
    'red',
    'green',
    'orange',
];

$count = count($values);
for ($x=0;$x<$count;$x++){

    $insertItem = "insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item".$x."Name) values";
    $insertItem .= "('','','".$values[$x] ."')";
    echo $insertItem ."\n"; 

}
```

**result:**

```
insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item0Name) values('','','blue')
insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item1Name) values('','','red')
insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item2Name) values('','','green')
insert into tbl (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item3Name) values('','','orange')
```

Comment: This answer was the most helpful. I have revised my question to better illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks Семенихин Максим

Comment: ok, i got what you mean. Look at code and result again

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you need to use this ,

```
$item1Name = 'blue';
$item2Name = 'red';
$item3Name = 'green';
$item4Name = 'orange';
$item5Name = 'yellow';

for ($x=1;$x<5;$x++){   
$insertItem = "insert into tblInvoiceItems (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item".$x."Name) values";
$insertItem .= "('','','${'item'.$x.'Name'}')";
runQuery($insertItem,$page);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use variable variable in PHP. Try this code:

```
$item1Name = 'blue';
$item2Name = 'red';
$item3Name = 'green';
$item4Name = 'orange';
$item5Name = 'yellow';

for ($x=1;$x<5;$x++){   
    $insertItem = "insert into tblInvoiceItems (invoiceItemID,invoiceID,item".$x."Name) values";
    $varName = "item".$x."Name";
    $insertItem .= "('','','".$$varName."')";
    runQuery($insertItem,$page);
}
```

Comment: you were error in your code

Comment: Edited. I wrote on my phone. Sorry. But the intention was give you the idea.

Comment: still has errors=)

Comment: ok.. I edited with the entire code. Now it's ok.